# Arrange a table followed by a table javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Currently, I'm working with two relating tables by a column name like "Container No".

My first table will be sorted or arranged manually.
When my first table is changed row position, the second table also need to be arranged with same position of "Container No".

Note: The second table can not contain "Container No" values like first table and can have multiple "Container No" values.

What is the best ways to sort the second table.
I've made a function to get old position of the 2nd table and new position after arranged as follow:

```
let cont1stList = [];
// List of Cont No after arrange 1st table
$("#cont_1").find("tr>td>div>textarea")
    .each(function () {
        cont1stList.push($(this).val());
    });
let mapCont1WithPosCont2 = new Map;
let pos = 0;
$("#cont_2").find("tr>td>div>textarea")
    .each(function () {
        let contNo = $(this).val();
        if (mapCont1WithPosCont2.get(contNo)) { // If have same Cont No, grouped by space to a text
            mapCont1WithPosCont2.set(contNo, mapCont1WithPosCont2.get(contNo) + " " + pos.toString());
        } else {
            mapCont1WithPosCont2.set(contNo, pos.toString());
        }
        pos++;
    });
// Arranged 2nd table with old row position
let newSortCont2 = [];
cont1stList.forEach(contName => {
    if (mapCont1WithPosCont2.has(contName)) {
        // split grouped text to each pos value
        mapCont1WithPosCont2.get(contName).split(" ").forEach(pos => {
            newSortCont2.push(pos);
        })
        mapCont1WithPosCont2.delete(contName);
    }
})
// Add exist 2nd Cont No to new Sort List
mapCont1WithPosCont2.forEach(existCont => {
    existCont.split(" ").forEach(pos => {
        newSortCont2.push(pos);
    })
})
```

Then I got the position 2nd table like:

OLD: 0 1 2 3 4

NEW: 0 1 3 2 4

I made a func to add new rows to the end of 2nd table then remove the first rows

```
let cont2Elements = $("#cont_2 > tbody");
newSortCont2.forEach(newPos => {
    $("#cont_2>tbody:last-child").append(cont2Elements.find("tr").eq(newPos).clone());
})
// Remove element temp row elements in 2nd table
pos = newSortCont2.length;
while (pos > 0) {
    $("#cont_2>tbody:last-child>tr:first-child").remove();
    pos--;
}
```

It's worked. But some behavior which I added to 2nd table's rows before was disable.

I think because of clone() func. Using insertBefore(), or insertAfter() will be fine to keep old behavior, but I dont know how to apply to this case.

Or could I create a temp table, then after sorting, I made a append to the exist 2nd table?

What is the best way to resolve this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hard to help without a [mcve]

Comment: I just want to sort a table which have the same column value with other table. When first table is sorted, then 2nd table will be sorted.

Comment: Using attributes would help. Get collection from first table in array ( or maybe your Map??) and you can use `sort()` on jQuery object for other rows and append sorted back to table. Would still be easier to help with a working demo

Comment: Sorry, I mean arrange, user can arrange manually. I've tried to append, but in the same table, if element is existed, jquery will move the element, not make a copy as I want.

Comment: I've solved it, tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
    let cont1stList = [];
    $("#cont_1").find("tr>td>div>textarea")
        .each(function () {
            cont1stList.push($(this).val());
        });
    let posEle = 0;
    cont1stList.forEach(contName => {
        $("#cont_2").find("tr>td>div>textarea")
            .each(function () {
                if (contName === $(this).val()) {
                    if (posEle == 0) { // Insert to first row of 2nd table
                        $("#cont_2>tbody:last-child").prepend($(this).closest("tr"));
                        posEle++;
                    } else {
                        let eleAbove = $("#cont_2 > tbody:last-child").find("tr").eq(posEle);
                        eleAbove.before($(this).closest("tr"));
                        posEle++;
                    }
                }
            })
    })
```